# Spark - pickling error when accessing RDD in loop

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm implementing a k-means algorithm in Spark. When I run the code below I get a pickling error (shown below). If I modify it and place everything outside of the loop, it will correctly calculate centroids.

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="Document Similarity")
lines = sc.wholeTextFiles(sys.argv[1])

articles = lines.flatMap(lambda x: re.split(r' ',x[1]))

shingles = articles.flatMap(shingle_pairs.get_pairs)

sig_vecs = shingles.groupBy(lambda x: x[1]) \
                   .map(lambda x: sig_vector.create_vector(x, a, b, n, p))

centroids = k_means.init_centroids(sig_size, k)

for i in range(max_it):
    # assign documents to closest cluster
    docs = sig_vecs.map(lambda x: k_means.classify_docs(x, centroids))

    # get count by key to use in mean calculation for new clusters
    doc_count = docs.countByKey()

    # recompute cluster centroids
    reduced_docs = docs.reduceByKey(k_means.reducer)
    centroids = reduced_docs.map(lambda x: k_means.mapper(x, doc_count))
```

The error is as follows:

```
pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception:
It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an 
RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations and actions 
can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; 
for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid 
because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed 
inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [SPARK-5063](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5063) "Spark does not support nested RDDs". You are trying to access `centroids` (`RDD`) in `map` on `sig_vecs` (`RDD`):

```
docs = sig_vecs.map(lambda x: k_means.classify_docs(x, centroids))
```

Converting `centroids` to a local collection (`collect`?) and adjusting `classify_docs` should address the problem.